# Documentación/Guía de inicio sobre XAF DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, programación-bajo-nivel

Buen día, acudo acá a consultar si alguien conoce algún lugar de donde obtener documentación de **XAF DevExpress**, adicional a la que brinda la página oficial del framework, indiferentemente del idioma en la que se encuentre.

De antemano, muchas gracias.